# Subtracting years pandas dataframe and adding them to a matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas date frame like this:

```
       maturity              coupon     freq
0 2018-06-01 00:00:00         3         1
1 2017-10-01 00:00:00         2         1
```

I want to have a matrix that in the first column contains these dates and dates 1, 2, ... years before these dates, and the second column contains the number of days from 2016.03.04 to the dates.

Like this:

```
    date                  number of days remaining
 2016-06-01 00:00:00          89
 2016-10-01 00:00:00          211    
 2017-06-01 00:00:00          454
 2017-10-01 00:00:00          576
 2018-06-01 00:00:00          819
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create new `DataFrame` by appending new `Series` by substracting [`DataOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html?highlight=dateoffset#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex) to list `dfs` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them. Last you can substract datetime `d` and `Timedelta` is converted by `np.timedelta` to `integer`:

```
d = "2016.03.04"

#append substracted column maturity with DateOffset
dfs =[]
for i in range(5):
    years_before = df['maturity'] - pd.DateOffset(years=i)

    #get only datetime to date d
    #print years_before.loc[years_before > d]
    dfs.append(years_before.loc[years_before > d])
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True))
print df
    maturity
0 2018-06-01
1 2017-10-01
2 2017-06-01
3 2016-10-01
4 2016-06-01
```

```
df['remain'] = (df['maturity'] - pd.to_datetime(d)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
#sort values by column maturity
df = df.sort_values('maturity')
print df
    maturity  remain
4 2016-06-01      89
3 2016-10-01     211
2 2017-06-01     454
1 2017-10-01     576
0 2018-06-01     819
```

I try to estimate max count of loop (not deeply tested):

```
#get max count of years => loops
maxYears = (df['maturity'].max() - pd.to_datetime(d)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') / (365.25)
print maxYears
2.24229979466

#convert float to int,  if 2.999 => 2, so one year is added
#rather add one more year (leap years, year is only estimated)
maxYears = int(maxYears) + 2
print maxYears
4
```